# can't install alfresco on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alfresco

i have been following this guide to install alfresco on my alfresco server
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-alfresco-community-edition-on-ubuntu-16-04

when ever i try to excute the installer i get this error

```
./alfresco-community-installer-201707-linux-x64.bin
-bash: ./alfresco-community-installer-201707-linux-x64.bin: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

when i use file command on the installer i get this output

```
alfresco-community-installer-201707-linux-x64.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
```

my server type is ARM64 can this be the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use an ARM64 binary of that program. X86_64 binary can be run with QEMU. But it may run slower than native performance.

Comment: do u know where i can find aflresco with arm binary

Comment: Sorry, I am not a user of that program and I tried to find ARM64 but failed :(